# How to get open HTTP connections count in Wildfly 8.2.0 using JMX?

Tags: connection, wildfly, wildfly-8

I need to get some metrics from Wildfly/Undertow, specifically open/max HTTP connections and used threads and correlate it with open database connection count, which I am able to read using jboss-cli:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS/statistics=pool:read-resource(recursive=true,include-runtime=true)
```

Is there a way to obtain the HTTP connection statistics in Wildfly 8.2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Wildlfy you configure the http connector thread pool specifying a `worker` configured via the IO subsystem:

IO Subsystem config example:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
        <worker name="my-worker" io-threads="24" task-max-threads="30"  stack-size="20"/>
        <worker name="default" />
        <buffer-pool name="default"/>
    </subsystem>
```

The worker then gets added to the `http-listener` (or `ajp-listener`) using the `worker` attribtue:

```
<http-listener name="default" worker="my-worker" socket-binding="http"/>
```

The IO Subsystem uses the XNIO API, that exposes the statistics in the Mbean `org.xnio/Xnio/nio/my-worker`. You can have a look at them with a jmx-client or jvisualvm:

[image]

[image]
But I have no idea how you can read them via jboss-cli.